# Error in passing data via prepare for segue

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3

I am passing the variable `x` using my prepare for segue method. The code is as follows:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "Restartseg") {
        var x = 1
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! GameViewController
        destinationVC.x = x
    }
    else if (segue.identifier == "Homeseg"){
        //pass more data
    }

}
```

But on the line `destinationVC.x = x`  there is a compile time error says:

> Value of type 'GameViewController' has no member 'x'

However, in the Game view Controller file under the class id, I declared the variable `x`:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
var x:Int!   }
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, try to clean and re-build.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
let destinationVC = segue.destination as! GameViewController
```

into

```
let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! GameViewController
```

Then Clean and build the project. Hope it works